Can a neural network learn element wise relationships of some matrix?
Suppose I have a dataset of matrices which I'd like to classify based on a hidden relationship between their elements. For example, let's have $\Pi_{ij} A_{ij} = B$ and if $B$ is the same then they share a label.
Would a neural network be able to learn this sort of relationship and be able to discern between matrices of different products?

Attention sort of does this
